# Formatting many checkboxes on Jframe or Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, jcheckbox

I have already a collection(List) of sentences. So I need to put every single sentences in a check box.The number of check boxes depends on the number of Vector Size. For example, I have 50 sentences, so I need 50 check boxes. Then user can check the desired sentences to be written in a text file.
The following class (ViewerFrame) is supposed to build a frame to have many checkboxes the same as the number of sentences in the array list(ManualSummarySys.sentences).Class (ManualSummarySys) is working perfectly.

```
public class ViewerFrame {

import java.awt.BorderLayout ;
import java.awt.Font ;
import java.awt.GridLayout ;
import java.awt.ScrollPane ;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent ;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener ;
import java.util.ArrayList ;
import java.util.List ;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup ;
import javax.swing.JButton ;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox ;
import javax.swing.JComboBox ;
import javax.swing.JFrame ;
import javax.swing.JLabel ;
import javax.swing.JPanel ;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton ;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder ;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder ;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalBorders ;

public class ViewerFrame extends JFrame {

    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 10;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 5;
    private JLabel sampleField;
    private List<JCheckBox> checkboxes = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();
    private ActionListener listener;

    public ViewerFrame() {

        sampleField = new JLabel("choose your prefered sentences");
        add(sampleField, BorderLayout.WEST);

        class ChoiceListener implements ActionListener {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            }
        }
        listener = new ChoiceListener();
        createControlPanel();

        setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        add(this.createCheckBoxes());

    }

    public void createControlPanel() {
        JFrame sizeGroupPanel = createCheckBoxes();


        JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
        controlPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

        controlPanel.add(sizeGroupPanel);
        controlPanel.add(styleGroupPanel);

        add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

    }

    public JFrame createCheckBoxes() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sentences");
        frame.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(), "Sentences"));
        for (int i = 0; i < ManualSummarySys.sentences.size(); i++) {
            JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox(ManualSummarySys.sentences.get(i));
            checkboxes.add(checkbox);
            checkbox.addActionListener(listener);
            frame.add(checkbox);

        }
        return frame;
    }
}
```

Comment: So apart from the fact that the `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default, which means you'll only ever see a single check box (the last one), and you're trying to add a window to a window, what's your question?

Answer (score 3):

You `extend` from `JFrame`, which is generally not advisable, but lets move on from this...

Then you call `createControlPanel`, which calls `createCheckBoxes`, which creates a new `JFrame`.

In `createCheckBoxes` you fail to set the layout manager for this frame, there by using the default `BorderLayout`, meaning that only one check box will actually be visible (the last one added).

Back in `createControlPanel` you try and add the frame that was created in `createCheckBoxes` to a panel.  You also try and add a object called `styleGroupPanel` which I can't find a reference to anywhere in your code...

Back in the constructor, you call `setSize`, this is generally unadvisable, instead you should be using `pack`.

Finally, you call `createCheckBoxes` AGAIN and try and add a frame to a frame.

You can't add windows to anything else.  Instead of trying to create another window in `createCheckBoxes` why not just return a `JPanel` instead?

Answer (score 2):

Why does `createCheckBoxes()` return a JFrame of all things? And then you add this JFrame to another JFrame? Sorry, but that makes no sense at all.

For my money, if I wanted to display a mess of checkboxes like that, I'd use a DefaultTableModel placed in a JTable. One column would be a Boolean column for the check box and the other would be the String column for the line of text.

Answer (score 0):

okay, I am pasting this code if it helps someone with a similar question. do note that here - the scroll pane contains the JPanel within, and the Scroll Pane is presented to the User on a JDialog (or showConfirmDialog). also has the "Select All" checkbox on top of the checkbox list.

public class Test implements ItemListener{

```
List<String> testset;
JCheckBox selectallcheckbox = new JCheckBox();
List<JCheckBox> testscheckboxes = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();
List<String> cancel = Arrays.asList("cancel");

public UserInputTest(List<String> tests) {
    this.testset = tests;
}

public List<String> GetCheckBoxes() {

    // Create Content Pane as JScrollPane and adding JPanel into scroll pane.  
    JPanel testspanel = new JPanel();
    testspanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(testspanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(testspanel,
                                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, 
                                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    pane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 500));

    // Create Swing Components and adding them to JPanel
    selectallcheckbox.setText("Select All");
    selectallcheckbox.setSelected(false);
    selectallcheckbox.addItemListener(this);

    testspanel.add(selectallcheckbox, 0);
    testspanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

    // Adding each element from string list to one checkbox into the JPanel 
    for(int i = 0; i < testset.size() ; i++) {
        JCheckBox testcheckbox = new JCheckBox();
        testcheckbox.setText(testset.get(i));
        testcheckbox.setSelected(false);
        //testspanel.setComponentZOrder(testcheckbox, i+1);
        testspanel.add(testcheckbox, i+1);
        testspanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        testscheckboxes.add(i, testcheckbox);
    }

    int x = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, pane, "Select Tests", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

    List<String> InputTestDetails = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (x == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
        for(JCheckBox getvaluechkbox : testscheckboxes) {
            if(getvaluechkbox.isSelected()) {
                InputTestDetails.add(getvaluechkbox.getText());
            }   
        }
        return InputTestDetails;
    }

    else if (x == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
        return cancel; 
    }

    return cancel; 
}


@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

    if(e.getSource() == selectallcheckbox) {    
        if(selectallcheckbox.isSelected() == true){
            for(JCheckBox setchkbox : testscheckboxes) {
                setchkbox.setSelected(true);
            }   
        }
        else {
            for(JCheckBox setchkbox : testscheckboxes) {
                setchkbox.setSelected(false);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}